# is there a google cloud service for complex/expensive (GPU) computations

Tags: google-cloud-platform

What I would like to do is similar to a google cloud function, however with more complex (and maybe also queued) computations.

A user submits an input form (for example to model a protein sequence), and as a result a gcloud instance is spun up, the task is performed, and then the results are returned.

I assume that this will not happen very often, so I would rather not have a server running all the time waiting for a request to come.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please give more context about the GPU ? From the question I don't see any use case of using Graphical Processing Unit( GPU ). Are you looking for a serverless option which has more resources or an actual GPU task ?

Comment: https://github.com/deepmind/alphafold - as an example. or molecular dynamics could be an other one.

Answer (score 0):

Just looked at the comment, so what you need is cloud run for Anthos. At the time of writing this comment cloud run for Anthos is the only serverless technology by GCP which has additional GPU support. You can get the details from [here](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/run/docs/configuring/compute-power-gpu)

However for this you will have to buy Anthos subscription, so please assess the costing.